# CLI node and jsconfig.json compilerOptions configuration

Tags: node.js

In my CLI node.js script that I run this way:

```
node -experimental-detect-module scripts/imports/index.mjs
```

And I want to be able to do the following in *scripts/imports/index.mjs*:

```
import readData from "@/scripts/lib/read-data"

// do stuff
```

My directory structure:

```
jsconfig.json
package.json
scripts
├── imports
│   └── index.mjs
└── lib
    └── read-data.mjs
```

and the *jsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now as you can see I have already figured-out how to use `import` itself (via `-experimental-detect-module`), but I don't know how to make the absolute-paths importing work.

How do I "load" the *jsconfig.json*?

Only constraint that I have is that I cannot change the `package.json.type` value, as all this is a part of much bigger project (Next.js, if it helps lifting it).